# Get output from Gitlab CI using docker logs

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on a script aggregating all job traces from pipeline’s jobs. My goal is to:

1. Send traces to Graylog server
2. Save job traces locally to make them accessible from the machine in case of Graylog shutdown.

My first thought was accessing the logs from my GitLab CI using using `docker logs` (or some other cli tool) on my machine with docker.

I know from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55444575/11456209) that it's possible to do from docker containers using for example:

```
echo "My output" >> /proc/1/fd/1
```

But is that possible to do from Gitlab-runner containers? My .gitlab-ci.yml for testing looks like this:

```
image: python:latest

stages:
  - test
test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - test
  script:
    - echo "My output" >> /proc/1/fd/1
```

Generally I would like to be able to get "My output" from machine using `docker logs` command but I am not sure how to do this. I use docker executor for my Gitlab runner.

I hope my explanation is understandable.

Comment: Your explanation is understandable, but what's the point of using _specifically_ `docker logs` if you don't know the container name? Why not just _access the logs_ instead of forcing yourself to use specific command line tool? Why `docker logs`? Why not access logs from gitlab api? It will be _just hard_ to use docker logs - you would have to get internals of gitlab-runner and gitlab to do it.

Comment: I am working on a script aggregating all job traces from pipeline’s jobs. My goal is to: 1. Send traces to Graylog server 2. Save job traces locally to make them accessible from the machine in case of Graylog shutdown. I thought accessing them using `docker logs` (or any other command line tool) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with any of the official docker-based GitLab executors. Job output logs are not emitted from the runner or containers it starts. All output from a job container is captured and transmitted to the GitLab server in realtime. The output never reaches the docker logging driver. Therefore, you cannot use `docker logs` or similar utilities to obtain job logs.

You can obtain job logs either: (1) from the [configured storage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_logs.html) of the GitLab server or (2) by using the [jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-a-log-file).

For example, you can run a log forwarder (like [splunk universal forwarder](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/9.0.0/Forwarder/Abouttheuniversalforwarder), [graylogs forwarder](https://docs.graylog.org/docs/forwarder), etc.) directly on a self-hosted GitLab instance to forward job traces to respective external systems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will stick with forwarding logs to graylog server using jobs API.

Answer (score 2):

[GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#gitlab-runner-156) (November 2022) might help here:

> ### GitLab Runner 15.6
>
> We’re also releasing GitLab Runner 15.6 today! GitLab Runner is the lightweight, highly-scalable agent that runs your CI/CD jobs and sends the results back to a GitLab instance.
> GitLab Runner works in conjunction with GitLab CI/CD, the open-source continuous integration service included with GitLab.
>
> **What's new**:
>
> - [**Service container logs**](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2119)
>
> **Bug Fixes**
>
> - [GitLab Runner on Windows in Kubernetes: error preparation failed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29000)
>
> The list of all changes is in the GitLab Runner [CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/15-6-stable/CHANGELOG.md).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner).

---

The Service container logs means:

> Logs generated by applications running in service containers can be captured for subsequent examination and debugging.
>
> **Please note**:
>
> Enabling `CI_DEBUG_SERVICES` may result in masked variables being revealed.
>
> When `CI_DEBUG_SERVICES` is enabled, service container logs and the CI job’s logs are streamed to the job’s trace log concurrently, which makes it possible for a service container log to be inserted inside a job’s masked log.
> This would thwart the variable masking mechanism and result in the masked variable being revealed.